# Scroll to the current time in Calendar view of Outlook using VBA

Tags: vba, date, outlook, calendar, appointment

I have this outlook VBA code that jump to the current time in calendar view as the outlook open up. everything seems working. The problem is it does select current time but it doesn't scroll to it. is this even possible if I am in yesterday.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    
    Do Until TypeOf Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView Is Outlook.CalendarView
        DoEvents
    Loop
        
        GoToCurrentTimeSlot_Updated

End Sub
Sub GoToCurrentTimeSlot_Updated()
    
    Dim oCalendar As Outlook.CalendarView
    
    Set oCalendar = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView
    
    ' Jump to the current date
    oCalendar.GoToDate Now
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method or property to bring an item into the view (scroll to the item).

The best what you could do is to add an item to the selection (before clearing it out), see the [Explorer.AddToSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.addtoselection) method which adds the specified Microsoft Outlook item to the selection in the active explorer. To be selected, the item must be selectable in the current view of the active explorer. Use the [IsItemSelectableInView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.isitemselectableinview) method to determine whether the item can be selected in the view. The item does not have to be visible in the view.

Comment: can you provide VBA code please? any jump start, I am new to outlook VBA

Comment: See [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office).